# CRUD Operation in Angular using WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

```js
employee.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { EmployeeService } from "../Shared/employee.service";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: "app-employe",
  templateUrl: "./employe.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./employe.component.css"]
})
export class EmployeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null) form.reset();
    this.employeeService.SelectedEmployee = {
      EmpId: null,
      FirstName: "",
      LastName: "",
      EmpCode: "",
      Position: "",
      Office: ""
    };
  }
  onSubmit(form ?:NgForm){
    this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe(data =>{
       this.resetForm(form);

     
     })
   

  }
}


Employee.service.ts

import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Employee } from "./employee.model";
import {
  Http,
  Response,
  Headers,
  RequestOptions,
  RequestMethod
} from "@angular/http";
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class EmployeeService {
  SelectedEmployee: Employee;
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  postEmployee(emp : Employee){
    var body = JSON.stringify(emp);
    var headerOptions = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({method : RequestMethod.Post,headers : headerOptions});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3184/api/Emp',body,requestOptions).map(x => x.json());
  }



}
```

```html
<form class="emp-form" #employeForm="ngForm" >
  <input type="hidden" name="EmployeeID" #EmployeeID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.SelectedEmployee.EmpID">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="FirstName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.SelectedEmployee.FirstName"
        placeholder="First Name" required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="FirstName.invalid && FirstName.touched">This Field is Required.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="LastName" #LastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.SelectedEmployee.LastName" placeholder="Last Name"
        required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="LastName.invalid && LastName.touched">This Field is Required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="Position" #Position="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.SelectedEmployee.Position" placeholder="Position">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="EmpCode" #EmpCode="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.SelectedEmployee.EmpCode" placeholder="Emp Code">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="Office" #Office="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.SelectedEmployee.Office" placeholder="Office">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <button [disabled]="!employeForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" (click)="onSubmit(employeForm)">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-secondary" (click)="resetForm(employeForm)">
        <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
namespace WebDemo
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
           config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
          
    //  methods:'Access-Control-Request-Method',
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here I tried to use Post Data on SqlServer on Button Press and it gives me this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
>   localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3184/api/Emp' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please help me to resolve, thanks in advance.  I used the reference [enter link description here](http://www.codaffection.com/angular-5-tutorial/angular-5-with-web-api-crud-application/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add origin option before url you need to allow:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

also you can allow every url like this

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

Comment: not getting whats wrong with var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

    config.EnableCors(cors); both solutions looks same

Comment: you need to pass the key for which you are passing the value, you are not passing the key in your case only you were passing the url you want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: now i used 
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true));                         now its shows Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  
Response:
headers: Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: 3
url: null
_body: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
__proto__: Body

Answer (score 0):

`400 Error` is clear indication of wrong data passing to server. Please check the `data` what server is expecting and the `data` you are passing from the `Angular` side.

Comment: <EmpTable>
<EmpCode>Ab0034</EmpCode>
<EmpId>1</EmpId>
<FirstName>Arul</FirstName>
<LastName>Jebaraj</LastName>
<Office>Automatebuddy</Office>
<Position>Developer</Position>
</EmpTable> data which i get where EmpId is Pk

Comment: And what are you sending from the Angular to Server ?

Comment: FirstName,LastName,EpmCode,Offc,Position

Comment: look at the response bro actually thats the data inorder to getMethod i inserted manually all are Varchar(50)

Comment: Solved it bro that was becoz config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:8080", origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)); nw i used config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")) and nw its works thank you for ur effort